# Where do I find the lightning node ID for my wallet in electrum?

Tags: lightning-network, electrum

Electrum supports running a lightning node for each wallet. I'm trying to find the ID for this node. Where can I find it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the GUI, you can find your lightning node ID by navigating to `Wallet > Information` in the applications menu bar.